# How do I re-center the camera to the axis?

Tags: camera

For context: I'm following the beginner's Donut tutorial, and I've reached part 11.

I've made a bit of a weird, unknown mistake which has resulted in the camera not being centered to the grid at all. Whenever I select "view selected", it doesn't recenter or zoom in to the selected object. Even worse, no amount of scrolling will bring the object any closer.

It's a really weird problem that I'm trying my best to explain.

[image: This is what my viewport looks like everytime I click "view selected"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: (solution)**
After viewing your .blend file, i made this little video clip. The 3d cursor needed to be moved.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKhNImt1bg8

---

Try pressing the hotkey <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> on your keyboard and see if you regain control.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/camera_view.html

By the looks of the current view, your flipped around (upside down) on the  Y axis.

Taking a screen shot of your cameras properties with coordinates and the Lens, Camera and Viewport Display panels open might help others, help you.

Posting your blend file would be most helpful.
[Including a .blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file/659)

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, but all Numpad0 does is bring me to the camera view. What I want is a fix for the viewport. – 

Here's the link to the .blend https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HkuGdLBk4IZ3OXm9MVky8PTbr2LpE-QY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, after peeking at your .blend file i made this little clip (also edited my post above to include it). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKhNImt1bg8

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help, I didn't think you'd go as far as making a small video. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Some times its easier to make a little video to describe a problem or help resolve an issues, less guessing or confusion.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your image, you can see the prism shaped black outline with something hanging off the bottom.  That's the camera.  What you're seeing in the viewport is the Viewport view.

You [navigate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html) the Viewport view using the mouse or various shortcuts.

To re-center the view on your donut, select the donut and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>Numpad .</kbd>  That's the period on the numpad, not the one on your keyboard.

If you don't have a number pad, you'll need to dig into the manual entry I mentioned earlier and find out which alternative works for you.